# What is the regular expression to match nested square bracket tags?

Tags: c#, regex

I created a regular expression pattern that matches square bracket, Wiki-type tags like the following:

```
[h1]Some content[/h1]
[b]some more content[/b]
[i]some more still[/i]
```

Here is a scenario:

```
This [b]sentence[/b] is just an [b][i]example[/i][/b].
```

Here is the pattern:

```regex
\[\w{1,2}\](.*?)\[\/\w{1,2}]
```

The thing is, sometimes the tags are nested. For example:

```
[b][i]nested tags content[/i][/b]
```

Nesting doesn't get more complicated than this. As would be expected, the pattern returns:

```
[b][i]nested tags content[/i]
```

What modification should I make in the pattern or what other pattern should I use for the match to capture the entire nested set?

Comment: What do you want to do with that?

Comment: Capture the outmost tag pair and the rest I have functions for. I just want an expression that returns the outer opening tag up to the outer closing tag.

Comment: What are possible inputs?

Comment: "Inputs? Here is [b]one[/b]. Here is [b][i][u]another one[/u][/i][/b]!"

Comment: That's not *"Wiki-type"* that's [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode), there are probably a lot of parsers out there you can use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex BBCode to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064453/regex-bbcode-to-html)

Comment: If you use greedy you either grab everything in the line or only capture the inner tags

Comment: Once you mention "nested" or "recursive", then "regular expressions" balloon into the realm of "impossible" or "frickin' hard". Are you sure regular expressions are the best tools you can use against this problem? In terms of your question of "What modification should I make" then I would simply say "rewrite this into something that doesn't use regular expressions". Frankly, it's going to be super-difficult writing the code and expression to do this, and good luck revisiting this code 6 months from now and understanding what the heck it does. Assuming you can write it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression don't do very well with the conditions you set. Especially when you have both nested expressions and multiple occurrences per string make it hard for a regular expression to parse.

It might be quite heavy to go that way, but a parser like ANTLR is better suited for this. And if you are capable, you can write you own simple string parser.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the question mark and get first group would be what you expected. ***? Quantifier** — Matches as few times as possible, expanding as needed。 But what you need is as many times as possible as the default acting. 

`\[\w{1,2}\](.*)\[\/\w{1,2}]`

Comment: Thanks, but a single line can have more than one pair and the greedy solution will skip in-between pairs.

Comment: My idea is you need to execute this regex expression recursively until there is no matched value. In another word, use match value to perform another round regex matching.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```cs
(?s)\[(\w{1,2})]((?>(?<c>)\[\w{1,2}]|(?<-c>)\[/\w{1,2}]|.)*?)\[/\1]
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/w0oWEf/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(?s)                         dotall mode
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\[                          "[" symbol
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(\w{1,2})                    one, two word characters
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
]                          "]" symbol
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
((?>(?<c>)\[\w{1,2}]|(?<-c>)\[/\w{1,2}]|.)*?) Nested tag part
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\[                          "[" symbol
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/                          "/" symbol
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\1                          Backreference to Group 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
]                           "]" symbol
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```